# Несколько join-ов в одно поле

Tags: sql, join

Есть таблица с продуктами:

```
-products
---ID
---NAME
```

Есть еще таблицы например с ценами продуктов:

```
-auto_prices
---ID
---PRODUCT_ID
---PRICE_AUTO

-moto_prices
---ID
---PRODUCT_ID
---PRICE_MOTO
```

Хочу взять результаты с полями ID,NAME,PRICE

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    NAME,
    PRICE_AUTO as PRICE,
    PRICE_MOTO as PRICE
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN  auto_prices ap on  p.ID = ap.PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN  moto_prices mp on  p.ID = mp.PRODUCT_ID
```

Но тогда появляется два поля PRICE
ID,NAME,PRICE,PRICE

Как сделать чтобы выбиралось одно поле PRICE

Comment: Может быть вам нужен `Union/union all`?

Comment: @Adil А вы определились с тем, какой именно price хотите видеть, когда записи есть в обоих таблицах ? Возможно вам нужно использовать case или другие функции для выбора конкретного из них, только вот функции в каждой СУБД свои, а БД вы не указали в вопросе

Comment: как вариант, для mysql можно в текущем запросе просто сделать `IFNULL(PRICE_AUTO, PRICE_MOTO) AS PRICE` Только зачем такие сложности? У продукта всегда есть цена, поэтому логично эту цену указывать в products, а не в отдельных таблицах. Тогда и вопросов таких не будет.

Comment: @BOPOH да так-то отдельно `auto_prices` и `moto_prices` не нужны.  Можно в одной таблице держать как мне кажется. В данном случае. Разве нет? При этом добавив колонку `catefory` и доп таблицу `categories` и связать их... и соотнести каждый товар к категории/типу ... что это фото, вело, мото, прото и т.д.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Более стандартный вариант, чем ISNULL.

```
    SELECT 
        ID,
        NAME,
        COALESCE(PRICE_AUTO,  PRICE_MOTO) as PRICE
    FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN  auto_prices ap on  p.ID = ap.PRODUCT_ID
    LEFT JOIN  moto_prices mp on  p.ID = mp.PRODUCT_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
(SELECT p.ID, p.NAME, ap.PRICE_AUTO as PRICE
FROM products p
JOIN `auto_prices` ap ON p.ID = ap.PRODUCT_ID)
UNION
(SELECT p.ID, p.NAME, mp.PRICE_MOTO as PRICE
FROM products p
JOIN `moto_prices` mp ON p.ID = mp.PRODUCT_ID)
```

А вообще, если у вас такая структура таблиц и там больше ничего вообще нет, может быть стоит сделать по другому?

Отдельно `auto_prices` и `moto_prices` не нужны.  `Price` можно в одной таблице держать. Прямо в `products`. В данном случае. При этом добавив колонку `category` и доп таблицу `categories`, связав эти две таблицы. Получится, что  соотнесете каждый товар к категории/типу ... что это фото, вело, мото, прото и т.д.  И тогда если захотите выбирать цену, в зависимости от товара, можно будет использовать ту таблицу с категориями. А в данном случае не придется делать лишних движений, достаточно будет написать

`SELECT id, name, price FROM products`